# Connecting to end point on Linux virtual machine in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to connect to mySQL db installed on Linux Virtual machine in Azure cloud. I opened necessary port by creating the endpoint. There were no firewalls settings for linux machine. But still I could not connect from outside world.
But I can connect to DB on the same machine.
Any Suggestions?
Thanks,
Kiran.

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: Be sure to include details of your endpoints and firewall settings. Otherwise, tough to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist to [enable remote access to mysql](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html),

- Update my.cnf to modify bind-address=0.0.0.0 to ensure the server is listening on all IPs (and not just 127.0.0.1, which is the default configuration)
- Update my.cnf to remove/comment "skip-networking" (when this configuration is enabled, all interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets).
- Grant access to the mysql user `logging in from specific IP` (instead of localhost only).

  - `GRANT ALL ON yourdatabase.* TO mysqluser@'yourip' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`
- Ensure firewall rules `allow tcp port 3306` (if firewall is active).